# php and jquery chained autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on a website where i want to do chained autocomplete using `mysql` database where i want to search the second text field using the first text field input

here is the html code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#name").autocomplete({
                    source:'node_fetch.php',
                    minLength:1
                });

            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form method="post" action="">
         Name : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
         Name2 : <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" />
  </form>
```

and here is the php code:

```
<?php
include('config.inc');

$term=$_GET["term"];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT root1 FROM tree where root1 like '%".$term."%' order by root1 ASC");
$json=array();

while($student=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $json[]=array(
                'value'=> $student["root1"],
                'label'=>$student["root1"]
                    );
}

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

i want to autocomplete name2 from root2 using input selected in name1
any help?  thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add select function in autocomplete options as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#name").autocomplete({
                source:'node_fetch.php',
                minLength:1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#name2").val(ui.item.label);
            });

        });
</script>
```

This will show selected item from autocomplete in the second text box.

Please mark as answered if that solve your problem.

Comment: sorry syntax error plus what i want is to make name2 autocomplete based on name selection in first field